# Как создать копию ветки на сервере у себя на локалке

Tags: git

Здравствуйте, клонировал репозитория, тут я перехожу в свою ветку git checkout origin/branch_name, теперь мне нужно создать копию этого branch на локалке? точно с таким же именем, как на сервере, совсем забыл, как это сделать, подскажите?

Comment: раньше один раз делал, помню что на локалке автоматом создается ветка с таким же именем как на сервере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не обязательно с таким же именем:

```
git branch local_branch_name origin/branch_name
```

Comment: только так? А как же автоматом?

Comment: скорее всего на крайняк так и буду делать

Comment: создать локальную ветку и вытянуть в нее одноименную удаленную ветку

    git checkout branch_name